# UITableViewCell Reorder Control - set backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom table view cell in my table view where part of the background is white and the other part is gray. Works all like a charm - until the reordering shows up:

[image]

My problem is that the reorder control  is all gray, but I want it to  be partly white, basically that it looks like a part of the table. I am able to get to the view using this code:

```
        for view in cell.subviews {
            if String(describing: view.self).contains("UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
                view.backgroundColor = .white
            }
        }
```

BUT: setting the view's background color to white here will look like that:

[image]

which I obviously don't want - I'd like to have the gray go all the way to the right side.
I tried all kinds of other modifications of the view (e.g. setting the frame's height a bit smaller, a CGTransform etc.) nothing seems to have any impact whatsoever!?

I'd really appreciate any hint to solve that!
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

this code should work inside your UITableViewCell. It activates editMode on it, find, hide subviews and resize Reorder Control on your whole cell. Key was to use layoutSubviews()

```
weak var reorderControl: UIView?
override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setEditing(true, animated: false)
    reorderControl = findTheReorderControl()
    removeSubviews(from: reorderControl)
}
private func findTheReorderControl() -> UIView? {
    return subviews.first { view -> Bool in
        let className = String(describing: type(of:view))
        return className == "UITableViewCellReorderControl"
    }
}
private func removeSubviews(from reorderControl: UIView?) {
    reorderControl?.subviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
}
override var showsReorderControl: Bool {
    get {
        return true // short-circuit to on
    }
    set {}
}
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if editing == false {
        return // ignore any attempts to turn it off
    }
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    reorderControl?.frame = bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Put the gray line on the section header view;

> 2.Set the cell's backgroundColor to white;

```
YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do is use backgroundView of cell.

```swift
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setupAtInit()
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupAtInit()
    }
    func setupAtInit() {
        self.backgroundVisew = UIView() //<- Here
        self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //The color you want to.
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // You can layout backgroundView as you want.
        // Basically, the backgroundView bounds is the same as self.bounds.
        // self.backgroundView?.frame == self.bounds
    }
}
```